# Allocate memory from a certain but big virtual address space (e.g. above 20GB)

Tags: c++, c, memory-management

I'll be messing around with memory sharing, and the godcake wants me to do what the title says, because above 20GB I'll allocate 256MB blocks(no other size, ever) to certain users and mmap(share) them with other processes. The 64bit virtual address space is HUGE (16EB). Its just that I need to keep the user manager's code and data somewhere seperated from the users' memory.

Perfect would be some function like this:

```
void *malloc(size_t n, void *from, void *to);
```

Comment: @Cubic edited.. cannot find anything similar to that on google.

Comment: Can I actually ask why the question is bad? I've used google, and placement new/realloc is definetely not something suitable.

Comment: Are you writing an OS kernel? If not, what OS are you using? Why do you care if the memory is above any particular value? How do you plan on sharing that memory once you have it?

Comment: The problem is that your "question" doesn't actually contain a question. It is pretty hard to see at which point you are having problems (and since you are the one with the problem, why should we work on guessing what the question is supposed to be?).

Comment: Linux 64bit. I just cannot find any library which would provide a function like that, which i darely need. Once I have the memory, it'll be memory mapped using `mmap` or some similar call to that.

Comment: Yeah, um, questions usually have a question mark in them. (One of these ?)

Comment: -1, @imacake: In general, "find me a function/library that does X" questions are not well-received. Are you asking someone to write this for you, or how you should implement it, or are you just asking for a function that does it?

Comment: @imacake: I suggest you rewrite this question to something like “How do I allocate shared memory and map it to a specific address?”

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you are on a system with POSIX support, you want to create or locate a shared memory segment with `shmget`, attach to it with `shmat`. When done, you detach with `shmdt` and remove the shared memory segment with `shmctl`. I leave it to you to read the documentation for these routines.

While `shmat` allows you to request a specific address at which to map the shared memory, there is generally no need to do so. You can pass zero for the address parameter, and `shmat` will pick an address. Setting a high address does nothing to separate the shared memory from other memory, except possibly to reduce or alter the errors that could be caused by buffer overruns writing to unintended places in memory.